# Key Hash error on second login

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api, cordova-plugins

I've cordova app which uses Facebook plugin to login - https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin

Everything works fine until my first login. As soon I try login in for Second time I get keyHash error. 
Note: When I try using debug keystore and apk it works perfectly. But when I try With released apk and app.keystore I face this issue. There are 2 different keyhash. I've added both keyhashes in facebook App setting.

Code:

```
$$('#login_fb').on('click', function () {   
                if (!window.cordova) {
                    var appId = prompt("9463534534441", "");
                    facebookConnectPlugin.browserInit(appId);
                }
                facebookConnectPlugin.login( ["public_profile","email","user_birthday","user_friends"],
                    function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) },
                    function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) });
            });
```

Screenshot

[image: Facebook Error]

Edit 1: Even I added Keyhash to facebook app setting, provided to me by facebook app. Still its not working

[image: Edit 1]

Answer (score 0):

Debugged apk and released apk might be considered as 2 different application from Facebook. So login to your Facebook account and delete the application which is connected to your FB account, from your user settings. And then try to login from one of the released or debugged apk (which you want to test). And be sure both key hashes are added in your FB developer account.